# Weird animation when expanding and collapsing a MaterialUI Drawer, how to fix it through CSS?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, css-animations

I have a simple MUI Drawer which requires some animation on it's expanding and collapsing.

The collapsed state should just be an icon, while the expanded state is the icon followed by text on it's right, with 22px in between them.

This is what the current animation looks like:

[image]

As you can see, it looks quite flaky.
I would like the icon to stay put regardless of the animation state. Upon expanding, the text shows up as the Drawer expands into it, and just disappears once it's off of screen during the collapse.

How can I achieve this?

Here is the demo of the app with styles and transitions I currently have:

https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-fast-qll47?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Any solution to this? I'm experiencing a similar issue. When my collapse opens it'll be slightly too tall and then snap down to the correct height. I have found that if I remove `padding` and `margin` that's associated with the `Collapse` (either in its parent, children, or itself) the "jump" goes away. Seeing an explicit `height` also works. Issue is I need padding on the `Collapase` children and I need the height to be dynamic.

Comment: @SnazzyPencil unfortunately I do not  fully recall how I ended up solving this issue. I think it had to do with moving around and adjusting the padding and margin along with the animation: The animation itself was done on the Drawer component while the padding was set on the ListItem in that Drawer. For your case, it would make sense to remove the padding/margin from the Collapse and try putting them on each item instead. Hope this helps! Best of luck